# reading Excel file getting unicodes

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am reading an excel file with pandas.

When i open the file in microsoft excel then I got the output like this

[image]

when I see this file in libre office i got the output like this,

[image]

So while reading the excel file, I do the following code but i am not able to get rid of  **x000d**

```
df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx')
df = df.replace(r'\n',' ', regex=True)
df = df.replace(r'[^\x00-\x7F]+',  '', regex=True)
```

Also there can be more unicodes like this in whole file.
The above code replaces all new lines from each cell.

Comment: x000d is a carriage return, not the newline \n. Have you tried simply explicitly replacing the specific character without using regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently I am only able to solve this issue by finding these types of unicodes and then replacing them.

```
df.replace({r"_x([0-9a-fA-F]{4})_": ""}, regex=True)
```

Let me know if someone having better idea.